# IsReadyToPayRequest returns false when I set the existingPaymentMethodRequired to true

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-pay

I am following the [Determine readiness to pay with the Google Pay API](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#isreadytopay) step in the [Google Pay for Payments > Android](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial) tutorial to determine readiness for the Google Pay wallet.

This works fine until I set the `existingPaymentMethodRequired` property in the [IsReadyToPayRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#IsReadyToPayRequest) object to `true`. My intention is to determine whether the wallet has at least one card but I always get `false` from the request. My environment is the [test environment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants#ENVIRONMENT_TEST) and the Android phone has a credit card registered. Does anyone know why?

```java
public static Optional<JSONObject> getIsReadyToPayRequest() {
  try {
    JSONObject isReadyToPayRequest = getBaseRequest();
    isReadyToPayRequest.put(
      "allowedPaymentMethods", new JSONArray().put(getBaseCardPaymentMethod())
    );
    isReadyToPayRequest.put("existingPaymentMethodRequired", true);

    return Optional.of(isReadyToPayRequest);

  } catch (JSONException e) {
    return Optional.empty();
  }
}

private static JSONObject getCardPaymentMethod() throws JSONException {
  JSONObject cardPaymentMethod = getBaseCardPaymentMethod();
  cardPaymentMethod.put(
    "tokenizationSpecification", getGatewayTokenizationSpecification()
  );

  return cardPaymentMethod;
}

private static JSONObject getBaseCardPaymentMethod() throws JSONException {
  JSONObject cardPaymentMethod = new JSONObject();
  cardPaymentMethod.put("type", "CARD");

  JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
  parameters.put("allowedAuthMethods", getAllowedCardAuthMethods());
  parameters.put("allowedCardNetworks", getAllowedCardNetworks());
  // Optionally, you can add billing address/phone number associated with a CARD payment method.
  parameters.put("billingAddressRequired", true);

  JSONObject billingAddressParameters = new JSONObject();
  billingAddressParameters.put("format", "FULL");

  parameters.put("billingAddressParameters", billingAddressParameters);

  cardPaymentMethod.put("parameters", parameters);

  return cardPaymentMethod;
}

private static JSONArray getAllowedCardAuthMethods() {
  return new JSONArray()
      .put("PAN_ONLY")
      .put("CRYPTOGRAM_3DS");
}

private static JSONArray getAllowedCardNetworks() {
  return new JSONArray()
      .put("AMEX")
      .put("DISCOVER")
      .put("INTERAC")
      .put("JCB")
      .put("MASTERCARD")
      .put("VISA");
}

private static JSONObject getBaseRequest() throws JSONException {
  return new JSONObject().put("apiVersion", 2).put("apiVersionMinor", 0);
}

private void possiblyShowGooglePayButton() {

  final Optional<JSONObject> isReadyToPayJson = PaymentsUtil.getIsReadyToPayRequest();
  if (!isReadyToPayJson.isPresent()) {
    return;
  }

  // The call to isReadyToPay is asynchronous and returns a Task. We need to provide an
  // OnCompleteListener to be triggered when the result of the call is known.
  IsReadyToPayRequest request = IsReadyToPayRequest.fromJson(isReadyToPayJson.get().toString());
  Task<Boolean> task = paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request);
  task.addOnCompleteListener(this,
    new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
          setGooglePayAvailable(task.getResult());
        } else {
          Log.w("isReadyToPay failed", task.getException());
        }
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the description of the `existingPaymentMethodRequired` property in the [IsReadyToPayRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#IsReadyToPayRequest) object documentation, in the [TEST environment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants#ENVIRONMENT_TEST) it should always return `true`:

> Note: In the TEST environment, if you set existingPaymentMethodRequired to true in an IsReadyToPay() request, the response always returns true.

Can you confirm that it is always returning `false` for you? That is: Is the documentation is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, that's the weird part. I have triple-checked the doc and the code. It appears that the API always return `false`. Not sure if this is related to any phone settings. I am using 2 brand new android phones.
Maybe useful information - if I don't pass this attribute, I get `true` and I can continue to trigger GPay flow can confirm the transaction with Stripe in a test environment.

Comment: Not sure if the wallet SDK has support that can reach out. I am kind of stuck at this moment.

Comment: You should be able to reach support through the "Contact support" menu in the business console: https://pay.google.com/business/console

Comment: Hey! I have the same problem with isReadyToPay(). Did you resolve this?

Comment: Note that it will only return `false` when environment is set to `PRODUCTION`. Are you using this in `PRODUCTION`?

Comment: why should it return FALSE on Production? 
if existingPaymentMethodRequired is set to TRUE, and Google Pay wallet has at least one allowed payment method, it should return TRUE.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise. It will return either `true` or `false` in PRODUCTION. It will not return `false` in TEST. i.e. It only works as expected in PRODUCTION.

Comment: For me it's returning false on Production and sometimes false on Test, even with a valid credit card. I tried multiple cards/google pay accounts, seems to me like the response is not always correct.

Comment: always getting onGooglePayReady as false in the GooglePayEnvironment.Test, I am giving my public and private key correctly

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in my app. Did you figure out what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

I have run the latest version of the [Google Pay API Sample App for Android](https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart) on a number of devices just now and the [PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient) method returns `true` for me regardless of the `"existingPaymentMethodRequired"` value when the Google Pay environment is set to [ENVIRONMENT_TEST](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants#ENVIRONMENT_TEST) and the `"allowedAuthMethods"` array is set to `["PAN_ONLY","CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"]`.

When the Google Pay environment is set to [ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants#ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION) and the `"allowedAuthMethods"` array is set to `["PAN_ONLY","CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"]`, then the [PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient) method returns `true` or `false` depending on the `"existingPaymentMethodRequired"` value specified and whether I have a payment method already saved in my Google account.

When the `"allowedAuthMethods"` array is set to `["CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"]` and the user does not have a payment method already saved on the device (in the Google Wallet app), then the [PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient) method returns `false` regardless of the Google Pay environment and regardless of the value of the `"existingPaymentMethodRequired"` property. But you have not asked about this so we'll leave this for [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74193658)!

Try out the [Google Pay API Sample App for Android](https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart) and let us know how you get on with that.