# Unexpected isReadyToPay behaviour when allowedAuthMethods array contains CRYPTOGRAM_3DS only

Tags: android, google-pay

If I define the `allowedAuthMethods` array in my [IsReadyToPayRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#IsReadyToPayRequest) object as `["CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"]` and the user does not have a payment method saved on their device matching `allowedCardNetworks` but meets all the other minimum requirements, then the [PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient#isReadyToPay(com.google.android.gms.wallet.IsReadyToPayRequest)) method returns `false` regardless of the Google Pay environment (i.e. [TEST](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants#ENVIRONMENT_TEST) or [PRODUCTION](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants#ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)) and regardless of the `existingPaymentMethodRequired` value (i.e. `true` or `false`).

Is this expected behaviour?

Given that the [PaymentsClient. loadPaymentData(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient#public-taskpaymentdata-loadpaymentdata-paymentdatarequest-request) method allows the user to add a card in flow (see screenshot below), I would expect the [PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient#isReadyToPay(com.google.android.gms.wallet.IsReadyToPayRequest)) method to return `true` if the `existingPaymentMethodRequired` property is set to `false`.

[image: Google Pay sheet screenshot]

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this behaviour with the [android-quickstart](https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart) sample. The call to `isReadyToPay()` returns a `Task<Boolean>`. Could this be your issue? If not, could you share your code and show how you invoke `isReadyToPay()` and how you check if it returns `true` or `false`? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It's the [google-pay/android-quickstart](https://github.com/google-pay/android-quickstart) app exactly that is demonstrating the behaviour which I have described in my question. The only one change you need to make to the app is comment out the `"PAN_ONLY"` value from the `SUPPORTED_METHODS` list in the `Constants` file. Then run it on a device that does not have any cards added in the Google Wallet app. I can fork the project and send you a link if you prefer. Let me know.

Comment: **Clarification:** When I said the `PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)` method returns `false`, I meant that as shorthand to mean that the `Task` object in the `OnCompleteListener.onComplete(task:)` callback has a result value of `false`.

Comment: Interesting. I did comment out the `PAN_ONLY` method during my testing. I will do some more testing.

Comment: @domi: Let me know how you get on with your testing please. If you're struggling to reproduce it, you can message me on Twitter or any platform you can find me on and we can arrange a screen share session in which I demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Hi - we are currently testing Google Pay in our website. We have `PAN_ONLY` disabled (that's a requirement for our gateway), the environment is `TEST`. I am using the code exactly as per the Tutorial (with the merchantInfo & gateway filled in, and PAN_ONLY removed), yet `isReadyToPay` is always returning `false`. I am joined to the Test Cards group, I have a card in my Google Wallet app, and the Sharing is On in my Payments profile and Chrome settings. I've no idea what else is missing! If I add `PAN_ONLY` back, the button shows without any issue (and the payment works as well). Any ideas?

Comment: **Update:** I paired with @domi on a call and we were able to replicate the exact same behaviour as described in my question on his machine. We came to the conclusion that this is by design and not a bug. I will clarify and explain this in an answer in this thread.

Comment: @Nuno: I think you're better creating a separate question for the behaviour that you're experiencing with the Google Pay for Web APIs. This question is focused on the Google Pay for Android APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with a Developer Relations Engineer at Google ([@domi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789738/)), I have come to the conclusion that the behaviour described in my question is undocumented but by design and not a bug.

The `existingPaymentMethodRequired` property in the [IsReadyToPayRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#IsReadyToPayRequest) object only has a bearing on the [PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient#isReadyToPay(com.google.android.gms.wallet.IsReadyToPayRequest)) result if the `allowedAuthMethods` array in the [IsReadyToPayRequest](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#IsReadyToPayRequest) object contains a `"PAN_ONLY"` value. Otherwise, the [PaymentsClient.isReadyToPay(request:)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient#isReadyToPay(com.google.android.gms.wallet.IsReadyToPayRequest)) API will treat the `existingPaymentMethodRequired` property as having a `true` value regardless of what value you've actually put there.

The rationale for this is that the Google Pay APIs are able to add a `PAN_ONLY` card (i.e. a card that's stored on file with the user's Google Account) in flow (i.e. in the Google Pay payment method selection sheet) but they're not able to add a `CRYPTOGRAM_3DS` card (i.e. a card that's stored on the device as an Android device token) in flow nor are they able to determine whether a `CRYPTOGRAM_3DS` card can be added on the running device (due to various technical reasons).

Comment: Correct @adil-hussain Thanks for putting the answer together.